# On click want to perform two actions

Tags: iphone, ios, uibutton

Here I write the code to move the imageView on click. I want to perform move up on first click and if it is clicked again it goes back. Here's my code :

```
-(void)gdown
{
if (penview.center.y > 428) penview.center = CGPointMake(penview.center.x, penview.center.y -5);
if(penview.center.x ==428)
{
    [movtimer invalidate];
}
}
-(void)buttonmover
{
movtimer=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.02 target:self selector:@selector(gdown) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
if(movtimer==nil)
{
    movtimer=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.02 target:self selector:@selector(gdown) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}
}
-(void)gdup
{
if (penview.center.y < 480) penview.center = CGPointMake(penview.center.x, penview.center.y +5);
if(penview.center.y ==480)
{
    [movtimers invalidate];
}
}
-(void)buttonmovup
{
movtimers=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.02 target:self selector:@selector(gdup) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
if(movtimers==nil)
{
    movtimers=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.02 target:self selector:@selector(gdup) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}
}
```

The method performing the click operations :

```
  -(IBAction)popupview:(id)sender
  {
   UIButton *button = sender;
   if(button.selected) //
   {
     [self buttonmover];//gooin up
    button.selected = false;
  }
   else
  {
  [self buttonmovup];//button goin down
    button.selected = true;
  }

  }
```

Its not working. The image view shakes while clicking. What change should I make in this method?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your else part code is getting executed. You should `maintain` a `flag` in your class for the same as selection property will always be true when button is tapped.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is right.Only do following change

```
movtimers=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.02 target:self selector:@selector(gdown) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

for every timer set repeat to NO instead of YES

Comment: this repeat i used it for animation,now problem is first click it worksproperly while clicking again it shakes in the same postion

Answer (score 0):

Your code is right.Only do following change

```
movtimers=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.02 target:self selector:@selector(gdown) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

for every timer set repeat to NO instead of YES

Ok if you want to show animation then change your if statement like this

```
//in gdown
if(penview.center.y <=428)
    {
        [movtimers invalidate];
    }
//in gup
if(penview.center.y >=480)
    {
        [movtimers invalidate];
    }
```